# The set of values of x for which $x^{2}-3\left | x \right |+2< 0$ is given by?

Tags: inequality, quadratics, absolute-value

So i could come up with $$(x-1)(x-2)<0$$

and whatever will be the solution it will also extend to the negative value of the $x's$ because the sign does not matter in this equation.

However i don't know how to proceed, Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Note that $x^2 = |x|^2$, so you should rather write it as $(|x|-1)(|x|-2)$. This is negative when one of the factors is positive and one is negative. Since you have $|x|-2 < |x| -1$, this is only the case when $1 < |x| < 2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $t=|x|$, so the inequality becomes $t^2-3t+2<0$, which is satisfied for $1<t<2$. Hence the original one is satisfied for $1<|x|<2$, which is the same as
$$
-2<x<-1\qquad\text{or}\qquad 1<x<2
$$

---

Just to make a step forward, if you have to solve $x^2-3|x|+2>0$, you can do the same and get
$$
t<1 \qquad\text{or}\qquad t>2
$$
Now the inequalities become
$$
|x|<1 \qquad\text{or}\qquad |x|>2
$$
which give the full set
$$
x<-2 \qquad\text{or}\qquad -1<x<1  \qquad\text{or}\qquad x>2
$$

---

On the other hand, an inequality such as
$$
x^2-|x|-2<0
$$
would give $-1<t<2$ which is the same as $|x|<2$. Why?

Answer (score 1):

If $x \geq 0$ then the condition becomes $x^{2} - 3x + 2 < 0$; if $x < 0$ then the condition becomes $x^{2} -3(-x) + 2 = x^{2} + 3x + 2 < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

you will get for $$x\geq 0$$ $$x^2-3x+2$$ factorizing this product we get $$(x-1)(x-2)$$
for $$x<0$$ we get $$x^2+3x+2$$ and factorizing this we get the product $$(x+2)(x+1)$$

Comment: These are mathematically correct observations, although it is not strictly speaking necessary to treat these two cases separately.  See the Comment by Sebastian Schulz on the Question itself for a unified treatment.  I would imagine the OP needs help *using* the factorization to solve the problem posed (only) in the title of their Question.